# DrawerLayout item click replace fragment from backstack is wrong position

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

In my app has 5 fragment (FragA, FragB, FragC, FragD, FragE)

Step 1. When app start FragA is open

Step 2. I click on drawerlayout item to open FragB then FragB is open

Step 3. I click on drawerlayout item to open FragC then FragC is open

Step 4. I click on drawerlayout item to open FragB then FragB is open

Step 5. I click on back button it's return from FragB to FragA not FragC. Why?

I think on Step 4 it's bring FragB to front and destroy FragC (not re sort position of backstack)

I want to bring selected fragment to front and sort position of backstack(not destroy) same this

```
1.before click drawerlayout item to open FragB again
FragA-->FragB-->FragC
2.after click drawerlayout item to open FragB
FragA-->FragC-->FragB
```

How to fix it's?

this is method i use to replace fragment

```
public void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
    String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens maybe because your first Fragment is contained within the default Activity, but you can try one of these:

public abstract boolean popBackStackImmediate (int id, int flags) or

public abstract boolean popBackStackImmediate (String name, int flags) or

public abstract void putFragment (Bundle bundle, String key, Fragment fragment)

Source: Fragment Manager Documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: I don't understand. How can i use your answer to fix may problem. Where? and When?. Please guide me step by step

Comment: These are methods that you can use to return to the previous fragment (previous meaning the last fragment you triggered, not the previous one in cardinal order) of an app. You can use them either inside your class (e.g. public abstract class Whatever), or a custom interface in which you need this behaviour to be featured (e.g. public interface PreviousFragment). Depending on the method you use, you'll have to put the required parameters for each one inside the ().

Comment: thank you very much. The problem because I don't understand life cycle of fragment in backstack. I can sovle it's by only addToBackStack() not popBackStack(). When I oopen new fragment it's add to backstack and when i click back button it's return to old fragment(not pop from backstack) it's work well for me.